# SonarQube - ignore ServerSide Includes

Tags: sonarqube, server-side-includes

SonarQube is telling me that the following line is violation according to the web standards:

```
<!--#include file="includes/headscripts.html"-->
```

But I want SonarQube to ignore this in general. How to do this at best? I tried to modify the rule, but that is not possible, right? Can I somehow ignore all lines containing `<!--#include`?

Please advice

*We are using SonarQube Version 4.5.4*

I have installed the following plugins

- Cobertura 1.6.3
- CSS1.6-RC1
- Findbugs 2.4
- Java 3.8
- JavaScript 2.9
- JIRA 1.2
- LDAP 1.4
- Motion Chart 1.7
- Timeline 1.4
- Web 2.4
- Widget Lab 1.6
- XML 1.4

Comment: You should add list with installed plugins + versions. This is probably a False-Positive in [Web Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Web+Plugin).

Comment: Do you mean here? 
`/sonar/settings?category=javascript&subcategory=libraries` 

Because the default value is telling me that jQuery is known already:
`Default: $, jQuery`

Comment: `sonar/updatecenter/installed`. Have you got problem in `*.js` file or other?

Comment: I have installed the following plugins
- Cobertura 1.6.3
- CSS1.6-RC1
- Findbugs 2.4 
- Java 3.8
- JavaScript 2.9
- JIRA 1.2
- LDAP 1.4
- Motion Chart 1.7
- Timeline 1.4
- Web 2.4
- Widget Lab 1.6
- XML 1.4